# Javascript: Reading values from JSON then pushing into stack

Tags: javascript, json, titanium

I can read the json from calcList1 in the if statement, and thought I could just push them into the l=[] stack. I am not sure what I am missing here, Because I am getting an error.

error:

```
"name": "TypeError",
"message": "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'l[0].z_param_name')",
```

loop:

```
var calcList1 = require('ui/common/convertd/calcs_db/calcs_models/outSort2').calcs_list;

var l = [];
var x = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < calcList1.length; i++) {

    if (calcList1[i].z_clac_id == _args.z_dex) {
        //>>>>this works>>>>>> Ti.API.info('>>', calcList1[i].z_param_name)
        l.push = ( {
            z_clac_id : calcList1[i].z_clac_id,
            z_find : calcList1[i].z_find,
            z_param_id : calcList1[i].z_param_id,
            z_param_name : calcList1[i].z_param_name,
            z_param_unit : calcList1[i].z_param_unit
        });

    }
};

Ti.API.info('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', l[0].z_param_name);
```

Comment: have you tried just logging l[0]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need equal sign '=' in here but I'm not sure if this is the main issue in here:

```
l.push( {
            z_clac_id : calcList1[i].z_clac_id,
            z_find : calcList1[i].z_find,
            z_param_id : calcList1[i].z_param_id,
            z_param_name : calcList1[i].z_param_name,
            z_param_unit : calcList1[i].z_param_unit
        });
```